# I am creating an Ionic App and getting error of cordova-res in adding android platform

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am new to ionic cordova and I am creating ionic app for learning purpose. Everything is working fine at 8100 port but when I try to add android platform using `ionic cordova platform add android --save` it is giving me below error:

```
cordova-res.cmd android
[cordova-res] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
[cordova-res]     throw err;
[cordova-res]     ^
[cordova-res]
[cordova-res] Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova-res\bin\cordova-res'
[cordova-res]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
[cordova-res]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
[cordova-res]     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
[cordova-res]     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
[cordova-res]     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova-res.

        cordova-res.cmd android exited with exit code 1.
```

Then I tried to install `npm install -g cordova-res` for installng resource dependencies but then I got below error:

[image: Error installing cordova-res]

I have also installed node-gyp and windows-build-tools using

```
npm install -g node-gyp
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

but after searching many articles online I have not got any solution for this problem

Cordova version - 7.1.0
ionic version - 5.2.3
npm version - 5.6.0
node version - v10.16.0

Please suggest the solution for above problem.